# JavaFX Создание копии объекта

Tags: java, javafx

Имеется конструктор, который получает какой-либо объект наследуемый от Node, т.е. в данный конструктор может быть отправлено как Pane, так и Label и т.п.

При получении объекта нам нужно создать еще один объект того класса, которого мы получили (Если получили Label, то создаем другой Label и т.п.). Каким образом это можно реализовать?

Comment: вам нужен клон объекта или просто новый экземпляр того же класса? и что с ним делать дальше (тем более в конструкторе)? в идеале покажите ваш конструктор, а заодно скажите, зачем это, потому как похоже на костыль))

Comment: @Дмитрий нужен именно новый экземпляр того же класса. В самом конструкторе не происходит ничего особенного, что стоило бы демонстрировать. Просто нужно создать экземпляр по получаемому объекту))

Comment: @SryForStupidQuestion сделать отдельный конструктор для Pane, Label?

Comment: @АртёмОконечников в данном случае в конструктор может поступить не только эти Pane или Label, а абсолютно любой объект наследуемый от Node)

Comment: какую цель преследуете?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Test {

    public <T extends Node> Test (T node) 
            throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        T t = (T)node.getClass().newInstance();
        System.out.println(t.getClass().getName());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
            throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        new Test(new Pane());
    }

}
```

Не имея понимая, зачем это нужно, судя по описанной задаче, можно сделать так...

Comment: А если конструктор не по умолчанию?

Comment: @  Артём Оконечников какие например ( мы говорим про неабстрактные классы наследники ноды)?

Comment: Человек пишет «абсолютно любой объект наследуемый от Node». Никто не мешает мне написать свой.

Comment: @ Артём Оконечников конечно не мешает. равно как никто не мешает создать в нем дефолтный конструктор. у любого подхода есть свои минусы. рефлексия еще и медленная...

Comment: @Дмитрий Спасибо, безумно вам благодарен!)